# Can I ask About Blynk in Electrical Engineering

Tags: support, asking-questions, specific-question, answers

Can I ask questions related to Blynk in Electrical Engineering?

Blynk is an App that allows comunication between A Phone,Tablet and etc. with Microcontrollers such as Arduinos.

[image: Blynk App Icon]

Comment: As an aside, "Arduinos" are not a microcontroller. An Arduino is a dev kit which uses an ATMega microcontroller.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about an app will probably get closed as *off-topic → not about electronics design*.

Microcontroller questions should be alright.

Arduino questions should be posted to [the Arduino stack](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Alright. Thanks